# Navigate to different page when clicking on the back side of my live tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have an application on Windows phone 8 with a live tile. This live tile is a flip tile. On the front side the title of the application is shown, and on the back side it shows some random news, and I'm wondering if it's possible to navigate to a different page if I click on the back side and launch the application when I click the front side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know WP 8.1 API does not distinguish between clicking on the front or back side of the tile. In the API, there is no way of knowing which side of the tiles appear when you click on a tile.